# Where are uploaded images stored in Magnolia CMS 5.0?

Tags: image, upload, content-management-system, magnolia, dam

I have created a custom dialog in Magnolia CMS 5.0 to upload images, in theory, to the DAM repository. However, after I upload those pictures, I cannot find where they are stored. They are not in the Assets module as fat as I have seen.

Does anyone of you have an idea of where I can access what I upload in Magnolia? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Basic+upload
Your image ends up as binary node directly under the node created by your dialog.
It might be better solution to create a link field that point to the DAM and use DAMs own upload functionality that will become available once you open selection of image from DAM.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Hi Jan. I have tried this for a while with no luck. Do you know how that link field can somehow point to the DAM so the upload dialog from DAM can be displayed and then the picture can be stored ? I would appreciate any further help that you can provide me with. Thanks in advance!